# How to configure qjackctl to combine output from mplayer and rakarrack? ("Audio device got stuck!")

Tags: sound, jack, audio-jack

If I launch rakarrack (without jack qjackctl), I do get sound output to my speakers from the guitar input.

However, if I try to launch mplayer, to be able to play along a song, it gives "Audio device got stuck!".

Then I lauched qjackctl and the same message continues to appear, obviously I have no clue how to set up qjackctl to use both channels.

Also, after closing `rakarrack`, I have to `sudo alsa force-reload` to be able to use mplayer again.

**How shall I proceed?**

System (let me know what is missing):

Linux Mint 17.1 “Rebecca” Cinnamon on thinkpad t400s

**Sound**

```
aplay --list-devices`aplay --list-devices

**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: Intel [HDA Intel], device 0: CONEXANT Analog [CONEXANT Analog]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```